# ITRS Geneos tool

Tags: monitoring, geneos

Is there a way to pass value to shell script from geneos GUI dynamically.My requirement is like , there should no password stored in any file . the user will run the script from geneos gui and dynamically pass the password through the GUI to the script .

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can do that using Geneos commands. For you reference I have added a sample screenshot of how your command will look like in Geneos Gateway Editor. 
[image]
Notice that it is set to run on Netprobe and the checkbox Enable password is checked. This means when you run this command from inside the Geneos Active Console it will ask for a password. Since this command is set to run on Netprobe, you need to define the password on probe. This is under the Advanced Section of Probe. See the below screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option to pass dynamic values to the Geneos Active Console. We have an option of storing encrypted passwords. This is available when we create a new variable under the environments category and select 'std encoded password' under the options field. This way, the password will be encrypted and will not be visible to any other user.